# React: Unable to navigate views with router after changing the state of Context (useContext)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, use-context

I have a simple setup to test the use of the useContext hook, when you want to change the context value in child components.

A simple Context is defined in its own file like such:

```
import React from 'react'

const DataContext = React.createContext({})

export const DataProvider = DataContext.Provider

export default DataContext
```

Then I wrap my router in a provider in a component that exposes its state to use as a reference for the ContextProvider, as such:

```
import { DataProvider } from './dataContext.js'

    export default function App(props) {

    const [data, setData] = useState("Hello!")
    const value = { data, setData }


    const hist = createBrowserHistory();

    return (
        <DataProvider value={value}>
            <Router history={hist}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
                    <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/services" />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </DataProvider>
    )
}
```

Finally I have two Views that I am able to navigate between initially, one of them showcasing the context value, as well as containing a button to change it:

```
export default function EndpointView(props) {

    const { data, setData } = useContext(DataContext)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{data}!</h1>
            <Button onClick={() => setData(Math.random())}>Update context state</Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The functionality seems to work, as the showcases text is updated.
The problem is, when I have clicked the button, I can no longer navigate in my navbar, even though the url is changing. Any ideas as to why?

This is showcased in this picture, where the url is corresponding to the top-most item in the side bar, even though we are stuck in the "endpoint view"-component.
[image]

Edit:
So the routing works by including a switch in the Admin layout:

```
const switchRoutes = (
  <Switch>
    {routes.map((prop, key) => {
      if (prop.layout === "/admin") {
        return (
          <Route
            path={prop.layout + prop.path}
            component={prop.component}
            key={key}
          />
        );
      }
      return null;
    })}
    <Redirect from="/admin" to="/admin/services" />
  </Switch>
);
```

Where the routes (which we .map) are fetched from another file that looks like this:

```
const dashboardRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/services",
    name: "Services view",
    icon: AccountBalance,
    component: ServicesView,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    path: "/endpoint",
    name: "Endpoint view",
    icon: FlashOn,
    component: EndpointView,
    layout: "/admin"
  }
];

export default dashboardRoutes;
```

Comment: Did you try to add "exact"  to the Route components?

Comment: Not yet, although i should firmly reassure that the routing works as inteded normally. Is is only broken AFTER i have changed the state using the Button's onClick handler

Comment: So you are sure it isn't about routing set up?  That seems unlikely, can you make a simple sandbox?

Comment: Will edit the question with an elaboration on the routing

Comment: @İlker Hope this clears something up, but it does seem odd, that the routing only stops working after updating the context state

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue.
I suspect the problem was that updating the state reloaded the root router component which caused some issues.
Instead I moved the DataProvider tag one step down the tree, to wrap the switch in the Admin component.